# How to determine the time and space complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, permutation

As I am preparing for an upcoming interview I worked on the string permutations problem. -

**Problem statement** - Write a function for generating all permutations of an input string.

Here's the solution that I feel is pretty good.

```js
function getPermutations(string) {

    // base case
    if (string.length <= 1) {
        return new Set(string);
    }

    var allCharsExceptLast = string.slice(0, -1);
    var lastChar = string[string.length - 1];

    // recursive call: get all possible permutations for all chars except last
    var permutationsOfAllCharsExceptLast = getPermutations(allCharsExceptLast);

    // put the last char in all possible positions for each of the above permutations
    var permutations = new Set();
    permutationsOfAllCharsExceptLast.forEach(function(permutationOfAllCharsExceptLast) {
        for (var position = 0; position <= allCharsExceptLast.length; position++) {
            var permutation = permutationOfAllCharsExceptLast.slice(0, position) + lastChar + permutationOfAllCharsExceptLast.slice(position);
            permutations.add(permutation);
        }
    });

    return permutations;
}
```

Even though I understand the solution (took me a few tries and about a million console logs), recursion confuses the crap out of me. Would someone please break down time and space complexity for me?

Comment: A bit about recursion: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2

Comment: Or the JavaScript version: https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs1101s/sicp/chapters/11

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Your question has broadened into a tutorial request, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think about the process. Say our String is `n` characters long. First, we must pass over each character in the string (`n` operations), and then for each character, recursively generate a permutation of the other `n-1` characters in the string, from which we will for each 2nd character, recursively generate a permuation of `n-2` chars in the string, and so on... until there is only 1 char left. To calculate the total time complexity, we multiply all these terms together (`n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1 = n!`), getting a time complexity in Big-O notation of O(n!).

To think about why we multiply them, we can think of the much simpler problem as follows: How many different permutations are there of clothes to wear if we have 2 pairs of pants and 3 shirts. The answer is clearly six, and we get this by noting that for each shirt, we have two choices for pants, so we take the number of shirts and multiply by the number of pants.

We can translate this example to a easy string, say the word "cat". To get every permutation, your code first chooses a character (it does not matter what order you choose the characters in, so I will first choose the 'c'), and then find the permutations in the remaining string, in this case "at". It is trivial that the only two permuations of this are "at" and "ta", so we add the strings "atc" and "tac" to overall permutations. Next, we take out 'a', and the remaining String is "ct", from which the permutations are "ct" and "tc". Thus, we add "cta" and "tca" to our overall permutations. Finally, doing the same thing when we take out 't', we end up with "ca" and "ac" as our remaining permutations, so we add "cat" and "act" to our overall permuations, and we are done. Notice that in this case they are all unique, but if a letter had been duplicated, (such as in "wow"), then your algorithm will double count, which is okay, as this not really necessary to account for.

Anyway, hope this helps, please leave a comment if you have an additional question.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The shirts & pants example really helped. O(n!) makes sense.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)